measuring NI 9215 for measuring pressure using pressure transducer
I need to measure pressure using pressure transducer with output of 0-10 V & 0-10000 psi range and NI 9215. How could be the code?

The Code could be in C, C++, C#, Python, Matlab, R, LabVIEW or a dozend other profgramming Languages. Please add more information on what you need. What Programming language for example and what your requirements are. Also show what you've already done and tried yourself!

NI provides plenty of Labview examples when you install one of their boards. In other languages- dunno.

I am using labVIEW software, graphical programming language. I have done simple code  by using DAQ assistant to get the measured value and this value is varying ( for example at pressure 1000 psi, the signal was 1 volts measured by AVOmeter, and in labVIEW was 1.01, 0.97, 1.001, 1.3, 1.9, 0.85, 1.01, 1.02, …. etc). how can I control this fluctuation on my measurement?
